# How to average user inputs with while loop using a sentinal value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a classroom assignment I have been asked to create a program that averages a number of user input exam grades using a while loop. I have come up with a functioning program, however it does not meet the specific criteria required by my instructor.
I need to Use a while-loop to allow the user to enter any number of exam scores, one number per line, until a sentinel value is entered.
How might I alter this program to get the same result using a while loop and a sentinel value of 9999?

here is what I have so far.

```
scores=int(input("how many test scores will you enter: "))
total_sum=0
for n in range(scores):
    numbers=float(input("Enter exam score : "))
    total_sum+=numbers
avg=total_sum/scores
print("average of ", scores, " test scores is :", avg)
```

The output should look something like this

```
Enter exam score. 9999 to quit: 100
Enter exam score. 9999 to quit: 95.5
Enter exam score. 9999 to quit: 90
Enter exam score. 9999 to quit: 9999

These 3 scores average to : 95.16666667
```

Comment: Your `for` is not checking any *'sentinal'* value and hence does not do what you say. Now for a `while`, you can use `while numbers != 9999:` but remember to initialise `numbers`.

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python input sentinel value", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think the best way to do it would be store the scores in a list and then compute the average of them after the user enters the sentinel value:

```
SENTINEL = float(9999)

scores = []
while True:
    number = float(input("Enter exam score (9999 to quit): "))
    if number == SENTINEL:
        break
    scores.append(number)

if not scores:
    print("You didn't enter any scores.")
else:
    avg = sum(scores)/len(scores)
    print("average of ", len(scores), " test scores is :", avg)
```

Comment: This causes the scores to always average out to 0.0 which i believe is due to the total_sum variable

Comment: @MeltedKendal: Oops...fixed. `total_sum` isn't even needed anymore. Thank you for pointing-out the problem (there as another related one, too).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to go about this. The general approach would be to keep a running total of the scores, as well as how many scores you've read, and then check whether the next score to read is `== 9999` to see whether or not to exit the while loop.

A quick version might be the following:

```
num_scores = 0
total_sum = 0
shouldExit = False
while shouldExit is False:
    nextScore = float(input("Enter exam score : "))
    if nextScore == 9999: #find a way to do this that does not involve a == comparison on a floating-point number, if you can
        shouldExit = True
    if shouldExit is False:
        num_scores += 1
        total_sum  += nextScore
avg = total_sum / num_scores
```

See how that sort of approach works for you

Comment: with a few changes this solved my problem beautifully. I do have some questions about the shouldExit function. I have yet to see this function but if i understand correctly here it is similar to using a =! 9999 function. is that correct?

Comment: It's not necessarily the most elegant way to go about it. One alternative would be to use a `break` statement after `if nextScore == 9999`, and making the while loop read `while True:`, and then taking out the shouldExit entirely.

The reason it's there is because the while statement evaluates its condition at the top of the loop, and does not execute at all if it evaluates to `False`. We want the loop to evaluate at least once, but not do anything if we read that `9999` value. The `shouldExit` flag is a way to keep track of whether we're reading something good or bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can just break out of your for loop after getting input.

```
for n in range(scores):
    c = int(Input('Enter test score, enter 9999 to break'))
    if c == 9999:
       break;
    scores += c
```

Something like that at least.